# JOIN to Subquery vs another with same exact results, takes much longer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Help would be greatly appreciated.

I have 2 different subqueries that returns same 3 columns, and the same results

Subquery 1 comes from a table, and takes about 30 seconds to populate
Subquery 2 comes from a function, and takes about 1:30 to populate

The problem is, the whole procedure with JOIN takes about 20+ minutes with Subquery 2, and only about 2-3 minutes with Subquery 1

Examples: Subquery 1 (table)

```
SELECT A.*
       , B.Company
FROM TABLE a
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT ID, 
                 NULLIF(ID_CODE,'0') AS ID_CODE 
                 Company
              FROM xyz
            ) b
  ON COALESCE(a.ID_CODE, CONVERT(Varchar(10), a.ID)) = COALESCE(b.ID_CODE, CONVERT(Varchar(10), b.ID))
```

Versus Subquery 2 (func)

```
SELECT A.*
       , B.Company
FROM TABLE a
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT ID, 
                 NULLIF(ID_CODE,'0') AS ID_CODE 
                 Company
              FROM Func_xyz
            ) b
  ON COALESCE(a.ID_CODE, CONVERT(Varchar(10), a.ID)) = COALESCE(b.ID_CODE, CONVERT(Varchar(10), b.ID))
```

I can understand that the entire join should take a little longer from the function, since the subset alone takes a minute longer, however, this drastic of a result?  I don't really even know where to start?  Any ideas would be appreciated!!

Comment: This would depend on your function also

Comment: Functions can seriously mess up your execution plan, check out http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29742/estimated-versus-actual-query-plan-with-function-calls

Comment: Also mentioned in the link but I wanted to point out: If you can write your function as an Inline function (without `BEGIN` and `END`) it will be used in the execution plan.

Comment: Even if I don't join right to the func subquery, and instead get the results into a #tmp, then join to that #tmp, it still takes a crazy amount of time.  Yet the output is the same as the original table subquery 1.  When I do an EXCEPT on both subqueries, I get 0 results.

Comment: Guessing as you haven't shown the plans but maybe you are falling foul of bad cardinality estimates and an inappropriate nested loops plan. What if you change `left join` to `left hash join`?